# user can't ftp to a directory but is part of the group that owns it

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

- I have set www-data as the owner and group on my `/var/www directory`.
- The permissions on `/var/www` are 775, so the `www-data` group has write access.
- user1 is a member of the `www-data` group.
- `vsftpd` is installed and I'm able to connect to the server through sftp as user1.
- I'm able to download from `/var/www` but I get a permission error every time I try to upload.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check in /etc/vsftpd.conf is

```
write_enable=YES
```